# Two threads concuration in main programm

Tags: java, multithreading, java1.4

I have program (`MAIN`) that has two thread that communicates with com port (`COM`) and TCP session (`TCP`).

If main (`MAIN`) program need info from `TCP` and `COM` modules it sends request message `R` (`tR` and `cR`). When threads have answer they send back answer `A` (`tA` and `cA)`. I have problem, when I send reguest to `COM` (`cR`) and without getting answer from it have answer from `TCP`- `tA`. `COM` `R-A` should be somehow isolated from TCP interruption. How to solve this problem using JAVA 1.4 ?

[image]

UPD. On `tA` event `MAIN`  initiates `cR` - request to `COM` port. Main can initiate request to `COM` by itself. I would like avoid to have second question to `COM` port without getting answer from first one.

UPD2. Actually whole system looks like picture below. `cR` might be started by `tA` or by `uR`. And `cA` can answer to `TCP` via `tR` or to `UI` via `uA`.
[image]
Following scenarios are correct

```
uR->cR->cA->tR-tA->cR->cA->uA
cA->tR->tA->cR
uR->cR->cA->uA
```

I'm getting troubles when two requests goes to COM at the same time.

```
cA->tR->tA->cR
uR->cR
```

I would like to allow new request only in case when COM returns answer to first caller.

Comment: Sorry Vico, your question is not totally clear. Is one thread dedicated to writing requests to the COM port, and waiting for the answer? And the other does the same for TCP? How do the two threads interact with each other? When you talk about "interruption," what exactly do you mean? In other words, two separate threads using two separate connections normally would not interfere or interact with each other in anyway; you'd have to write code to coordinate them. What do you have there?

Comment: What do you mean by "concuration"?

Comment: I have updated my question in message body

Comment: I updated [my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32082070/3474)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly you have 2 threads in main method. 1 thread is interacting with with TCP and another with COM. Right?
If this is the case than what you can do is you can let handle thread 1 to handle all TCP request/response and thread 2 to handle all COM request/response. And the main thread is not aware of this. Until the time both thread finish their job independently the main threads wait and once both thread are done with their job, Main thread can resume its work. hence the communication of COM and TCP is completley separate. you can use Threads "join()" method here.

Did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example that can explain your system. Here i have made a environment of caller receiver. Until caller not end with his or her statement receiver can not start with saying anything or respond to caller.

**Caller.java**

```
public class Caller implements Runnable {

    MaintainACall call;

    Caller(MaintainACall me)
    {
        call=me;
        new Thread(this,"Mr X").start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        String a[]={"Hello how r u", "I'm in vadodara"};
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {

            call.sayHello(a[i]);
        }

    }

}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
public class Reciver implements Runnable {

    MaintainACall call;

    Reciver(MaintainACall call)
    {
        this.call=call;
        new Thread(this,"Mr Y").start();
    }
    public void run()
    {

        call.Wtshesay();

    }

}
```

**MaintainACall.java**

```
public class MaintainACall {

    String say;
    boolean valueSet=false;

    synchronized String Wtshesay()
    {
        while(!valueSet)
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        System.out.println("I have heared "+say);
        valueSet=false;
        notify();
        return say;
    }

    synchronized void sayHello(String msg)
    {
        while(valueSet)
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ie)
            {
                System.out.println(ie);
            }
        say=msg;
        valueSet=true;
        System.out.println("She says "+say);        
        notify();
    }

}
```

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        MaintainACall my=new MaintainACall();
        new Caller(my);
        new Reciver(my);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use multiple threads. Just read the request from the socket, synchronously process the request by communicating over the COM port, and then write the response over the socket.

There may be reasons to use multiple threads, though. For example, perhaps you want to be able to respond to socket requests with a time-out error if the COM port doesn't respond fast enough, but the serial port library you are using doesn't support a time-out configuration. In that case, you'll have to clarify your requirements. What do you want to happen if another request is received from the socket, but the COM thread is still stuck handling a previous request? You could wait, respond with an error immediately, etc.

Create a [single-thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) [`ExecutorService`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) Whenever you need to interact with the COM port, whether the request originates from the socket or from the main program itself, [submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) the task to this service. This will ensure that serial communications won't be interleaved with competing requests.

The basic idea here is to allow only one thread to use the COM port, consuming a queue of tasks produced by various other threads.